# Odd behavoir from validation script

Tags: validation

I have this script and form that I alteret so that I can pass a variable. The original was called by onSubmit='return validateForm()'. After altering the script, only onClick will work. If using onSubmit, it just submits thr form no matter checked og not.

Can anybody tell me why the difference in behavior?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm(a) {
var radios = document.getElementsByName('tjek' + [a]);
var radiosChecked = false;

var i = 0;
while (!radiosChecked && i < radios.length) {
    if (radios[i].checked) radiosChecked = true;
    i++;
}


if (!radiosChecked) {
    alert("Du skal vælge en mulighed!")
    return false;
}
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<form name="Form" action="http://google.com" method="get">
    <input name="tjek1" type="radio" value="" />
    <input name="tjek1" type="radio" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" onClick="return validateForm(1)" />
</form>

<form name="Form" action="http://bing.com" method="get">
    <input name="tjek2" type="radio" value="" />
    <input name="tjek2" type="radio" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" onClick="return validateForm(2)"  />
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I posted an answer a day ago. Any response?

Answer (score 0):

I see no difference in behavior: [live demo](http://jsbin.com/qowon/1/edit?html,output).

The used code, in which I essentially only changed the `onclick` to `onsubmit`, and only in the first form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm(a) {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('tjek' + [a]);
    var radiosChecked = false;
    var i = 0;
    while (!radiosChecked && i < radios.length) {
        if (radios[i].checked) radiosChecked = true;
        i++;
    }
    if (!radiosChecked) {
        alert("Du skal vælge en mulighed!")
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="Form" onsubmit="return validateForm(1)" action="http://google.com" method="get">
        <input name="tjek1" type="radio" value="" />
        <input name="tjek1" type="radio" value="" />
        <input type="submit" value="Send"  />
    </form>
    <form name="Form" action="http://bing.com" method="get">
        <input name="tjek2" type="radio" value="" />
        <input name="tjek2" type="radio" value="" />
        <input type="submit" value="Send" onClick="return validateForm(2)"  />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```